# How to show y axis in log scale with only powers of 10 using plot in R

Tags: r, plot, scale, axis, logarithm

I would like to do a plot in R (using the *plot* function) with log scale on Y axis which shows on the y axis only the power of 10 in a style like 10, 100, 1000... Is it possible ? I do not like the solution with *xant="n"* or *yant="n"* , explained [here](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html), which suppress x-axis or y-axis, because if I use a code like:

```
plot(x33,y33,log = "x",xaxt="none",xlab =xlab.text ,ylab = "Signal Density (a.u.)",main=expression('Relaxation times distribution - H'[2]*'O'),
     las=1,cex.main=1,font.main=2,font.lab=2, cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=0.7,type = "l",lwd=1.5,
     col="red",ylim = c(0,2000))

axis(1, 10^seq(0L,6L,2L),cex.axis=0.7)
```

it shows me axis with 1e+00,1e+02...and I do not like this format. If I use the same code with seq() instead of 10^seq(0L,6L,2L), how can I say it to print only powers of 10 ? I know xant and yant are the straightforward solution but I do not know how to use them such that I can print 10, 100, 1000...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699493/transform-only-one-axis-to-log10-scale-with-ggplot2

Comment: If you want fine control over the axis of a base plot, I'm not aware of any way other than suppressing the axis in the original `plot()` call and then specifying how you want it to appear with `axis()`. Can you say more about what you "do not like" about that solution?

Comment: @GregorThomas you are right. I modified the post to make what I mean clear.

Answer (score 1):

This post appears to answer your question. The log scale is applied to the x axis in this example, so just change that to y axis.

[Logarithmic scale plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890742/logarithmic-scale-plot-in-r)

Comment: Hi thank you but, as I wrote in the post that I have modified, I do not really like the format with 1e+00,1e+02 etc... :( I would like to say it to print 10, 100,1000...

Comment: With `axis` you can use the `labels` and `at` arguments to specify exactly the labels you want at the locations you want.